# Secure Authentication cookie Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, cookies

I have two page P1.aspx(login page) and P2.aspx(redirect page), both configured with SSL.
In P1.aspx I created the authentication cookie with "Secure" property set to "true" and added in response object of the P1.aspx.

But when the page is redirected to P2.aspx from P1.aspx,the authentication cookie in P2.aspx request shows the cookie's "Secure" property as "false". I am not getting why "Secure" property is set to "false" in requests cookie.

Comment: If you are checking `Secure` on server side, then it won't be true, because browser doesn't send this attribute back. But if you check it in Chrome DevTools, then you can find that this cookie has Secure = true

Comment: In response object(P1.aspx) property is showing "true", but in request object(P2.aspx) it is "false". Both cookie should be same right?Can client set this property to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking Secure on server side, then it won't be true, because browser doesn't send this attribute back. But if you check it in Chrome DevTools, then you can find that this cookie has Secure = true.

Here is a quote from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> Besides the name–value pair, servers can also set these cookie attributes: a cookie domain, a path, expiration time or maximum age,
>   Secure flag and HttpOnly flag. **Browsers will not send cookie
>   attributes back to the server. They will only send the cookie’s
>   name-value pair**. Cookie attributes are used by browsers to determine
>   when to delete a cookie, block a cookie or whether to send a cookie
>   (name-value pair) to the servers.

So it's totally fine that you don't Secure attribute in Request, and has it in Response when you send it. Browser just don't send it back in each request, but it still use it anyway, and if request wont be HTTPS, then browser won't use this cookie